# Is it appropriate to view Maven as the equivalent of conda in Python ecosystem, or something else?

Tags: java, python, maven

[Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) is a software project management and comprehension tool. Based on the concept of a project object model (POM), Maven can manage a project's build, reporting and documentation from a central piece of information.

[Conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) is an open source package management system and environment management system

Is it appropriate to view Maven as the equivalent of conda in Python ecosystem, or something else?

Comment: I would say similar, however Java (unlike Python) has no defined "system packages". Thus it is only similar in the context of building software, no environment management per se.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch is it appropriate to view the built-in class like String in java the equivalent system packages in python?

Comment: Not everything has an equivalent, the languages fundamentally differ. I would say no, since you can't install more with "pip". Best of luck.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Would you please give more detail about 'can't install more with "pip"' thanks in advance.

Comment: I really don't know how to add more, there is no equivalent to pip in Java (whereas conda contains the functionality of pip *and* managed environments). You mentioned String but let's consider `Integer`, Java has `int` and `Integer` which are a primitive type and a wrapper for that 32-bit primitive type respectively; but the closest equivalent to a python `int` is `BigInteger` - because a python `int` has arbitrary precision.